# Several intern methods error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use several methods, but it throws an error in my console. This is my code:

```
var Amber = {
    Notification: function (type) {
         this.message = null;
         this.box = null;

         switch(type) {
              case 'bad':
                   this.box = '<div class="Notification bad><i class="icon-notok"></i>' + this.message + '</div>';
              break;

              case 'good':
                   this.box = '<div class="Notification good><i class="icon-ok"></i>' + this.message + '</div>';
              break;

              case 'informative':
                   this.box = '<div class="Notification informative><i class="icon-informative"></i>' + this.message + '</div>';
              break;

              case 'warning':
                   this.box = '<div class="Notification warning><i class="icon-warning"></i>' + this.message + '</div>';
              break;
         }

         this.SetMessage = function (message) {
              this.message = message;
         }

         this.Show = function () {
              this.box.appendTo(document.body);
         }
    },
```

```
    new Amber.Notification('bad').SetMessage('lol').Show();
```

In Mozilla Firefox, I get this error:

```
TypeError: (intermediate value).SetMessage(...) is undefined
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return `this` from the function calls to chain them like that, otherwise you are returning `undefined` and trying to call a function on undefined

```
     this.SetMessage = function (message) {
          this.message = message;
          return this;
     }

     this.Show = function () {
          this.box.appendTo(document.body);
          return this;
     }
```

`appendTo` is a jQuery function. Right now your `box` is just a string. To make it a selector you can do

```
this.box = $('<div class="Notification bad><i class="icon-notok"></i>' + this.message + '</div>');
```

Then you should be able to call `appendTo`. It's a helpful convention to prefix variables that are selectors with `$`. This is nice because it shows that the variable is a selector

```
this.$box = $('<div class="Notification bad><i class="icon-notok"></i>' + this.message + '</div>');
...
this.Show = function () {
    this.$box.appendTo(document.body);
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Well, it accually worked but not for `this.box`. My console says `TypeError: this.box.appendTo is not a function`.